# File not compiling due to syntax error on ';' (semi-colon)

Tags: visual-c++

My Visual Studio 2010 does not allow my file to be compiled when I use the semi-colon characters (";")/  It says there is an error.

But not all of the semi-colons, just one of them.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: waynekwa, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 7/11/2012 11:58:46 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\waynekwa.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  waynekwa.cpp
1>c:\users\asus\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\waynekwa\waynekwa\waynekwa.cpp(6): warning C4996: 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdio.h(304) : see declaration of 'scanf'
1>c:\users\asus\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\waynekwa\waynekwa\waynekwa.cpp(11): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\users\asus\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\waynekwa\waynekwa\waynekwa.cpp(11): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ')'
1>c:\users\asus\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\waynekwa\waynekwa\waynekwa.cpp(11): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ')'
1>c:\users\asus\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\waynekwa\waynekwa\waynekwa.cpp(12): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\asus\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\waynekwa\waynekwa\waynekwa.cpp(27): fatal error C1075: end of file found before the left brace '{' at 
'c:\users\asus\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\waynekwa\waynekwa\waynekwa.cpp(3)' was matched
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:02.14
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The code:

```
#include<stdio.h> 

int main(void) { 
    int num,x,y=0; 
    printf("enter range:"); 
    scanf("%i",&num); 
    for(x=1;x<=;x++) { 
        if(num%x==0) { 
            y++; 
        } 
        if(y==2) { 
            printf("it is prime number.\n"); 
        } else { 
            printf("it is not prime number.\n"); 
        } 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You need to post the contents of "waynekwa.cpp". Even SO has limited psychic abilities.

Comment: @user1518412: I removed your PS about emailing. If you want people here to help you, then post the relevant source code here -- noone's going to ask you for it by email. Remember, it is *you* who wants an issue solved, so *you* have to make the initial effort of fully describing the problem.

Comment: It looks like your code has syntax errors, mostly on the 11th and 27th lines of your code

Comment: Also, please choose a more reasonable title for your question. Apparently there is nothing wrong with your installation of VS, only with the source code your trying to compile.

Comment: -1 for no source code when asked for it.  If I come back to this question sometime in the future and see that source code was added, i'll remove the -1

Comment: but i am the only one that cant compile this file in the whole class because of the ';'

Comment: and this is what im compiling

#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
 int num,x,y=0;
 printf("enter range:");
 scanf("%i",&num);




 for(x=1;x<=;x++)
 {
 if(num%x==0)
 {
  y++;
 }
 if(y==2)
 {
  printf("it is prime number.\n");
 }
 else
 {
  printf("it is not prime number.\n");
 }
 return 0;
 }

Comment: You need to post that information by editing the question.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you forgot a closing bracket for your `for` loop. You need one between the `else` of the second `if` and your `return`. This is the cause of the second actual error, `fatal error C1075: end of file found before the left brace '{'`.

Also, `for (x = 1; x <= ; x++)` is not a valid for loop. The second part `x <= ;` is missing a value to compare against. For example, `x <= 10;`. That's where the syntax error `error C2059: syntax error : ';'` is coming from. The other complaints about semicolons are due to this error.

**Edit:**
Also, your assignment `int num,x,y=0;` is difficult to understand. I recommend you clean it up, either by putting on multiple lines or by chain assigning.

Answer (score 0):

Given the information you have given us, you probably need to add or remove one or more `;` then add a `}` somewhere after line 3. But you also may not need to do these things.

Comment: Thought you might like to know he posted the code in a comment on the question. I suggested an edit, but it's there if you want to update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is the line:

```
for(x=1;x<=;x++) {
```

you have a `x<=` just sitting there alone, you have to put a value there.

I'm guessing that you meant:

```
for(x=1; x<=num; x++) {
```

But other than that, no other syntax errors are jumping out at me.